# Rounded button above the UISCROLLVIEW

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have been working in a project which has a uiscroll view where the uiscroll view size is set programatically with height 225 and width is self. I have created two uiimageView where it displays two images and I have animated it by moving using a page view controller. Finally the image moves atomically like a slide show with page view controller. I have removed the navigation controller do I need to keep a back button for navigation when I place a unbutton above uiscrollview it was stating like scrollview ambitious scrolling content. I need to place a rounded back button above scroll view. I have attached the image of my storyboard. When I tried to place a button it is not visible in stimulator [header scroll view is the UISCROLLVIEW where the animated image is placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P03z6.png)

Comment: you need to add a UIView First in ScrollView that will act as its ContentView and then You can add UIbutton inside that ContentView

Comment: change your hierarchy and check

Comment: I have tried adding a uiview inside it and added a button inside the uiview it was not visible in stimulator and also the animation is not working.

Comment: we can change the hierarchy only inside the header scroll view @Anbu.karthik